# How to extract workflow action name in oozie

Tags: hadoop2, oozie, oozie-workflow

I have many java actions. I have to extract the action names. 
Is there any EL function to extract action name?

Comment: Whats your use case?

Comment: Oozie passes a lot of information to its "launcher" process via multiple XML files, that define Java and Hadoop properties.So your custom java code should be able to either scan the XML files to retrieve the current Action name, or simply get it from the appropriate system property. I did the trick some years ago, but with a shell action, so I had to go for the XML files and never really investigated the Java system props...

Comment: Just look at the YARN logs for one of your Java actions -- the beginning of "stdout" should list all the files present in the container's working dir *(including the XML with the props)*, then it should also list all the system props set in the "launcher" JVM...